# Azure co-located cache session state (instance failure/updates)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-caching

How does azure co-located cache when used for session state through the DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider handle scenarios where the instances is updated (rolling/incremental) or if there is a failure on one of the instances.

Is all co-located cache data replicated to all instances or is some data lost on failures?

If for example request #1 is handle by instance 0 and then instance 0 crashes/updates can request #2 that is handled by instance 1 continue to access the same Session state data from the previous request?

Any ides or can somebody point me to any good resources describing cases like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use with SessionState you have to [configure the caching role](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#enable-caching) with "High Availability". This will make all cache entries distributed among all instances of the role. So a cache item will not be lost upon instance updates / recycles.